# Javascript slice string by symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get from this html code

```
<a href="www.realy-long-link.com">Link<a>
```

Href value looking like this - Realy Long Link and append it into body.

Here is what I done now.

```
$("a").hide();
$("body").append($("a").attr("href"));
```

Goal is:

- Remove *www.* at the start and *.com* at the end.
- Symbol - replace with space.
- Upercase each first character

You  can edit my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWzJXM?editors=1010

Comment: What have you tried? Your codepen is only appending the href to the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
a[0].style.display = 'none';
document.body.innerHTML += a[0].getAttribute('href')
  // remove www. and .com
  .replace(/^www\.|\.com$/g, '')
  // convert first letter to upper case
  .replace(/\b\w/g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase()
  })
  // replace - with space
  .replace(/-/g, ' ')
```

```html
<a href="www.realy-long-link.com">Link<a>
```

---

Although you can do it without any regex

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
a[0].style.display = 'none';
document.body.innerHTML += a[0].getAttribute('href')
  // split based on `'`
  .split('.')
  // remove `www` and  `com` from array
  .slice(1, -1)
  // join again
  .join('.')
  // split based on `-`
  .split('-')
  // capitalize first letter
  .map(function(v) {
    return v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1);
  })
  // join by space
  .join(' ')
```

```html
<a href="www.realy-long-link.com">Link<a>
```

---

**UPDATE :** JQuery solution with the same code

```js
$('body').append($('a').hide().attr('href').replace(/^www\.|\.com$/g, '').replace(/\b\w/g, function(m) {
  return m.toUpperCase();
}).replace(/-/g, ' '));

//or
/*

$('body').append($('a').hide().attr('href').split('.').slice(1, -1).join('.').split('-').map(function(v) {
  return v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1);
}).join(' '));

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.realy-long-link.com">Link<a>
```